# Typescript generic class parameters

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am currently programming some internal abstract class for project and I need it to be generic (I want it to be extendable).

I want my class to be called as it would extend the T template like `Sample extends T`, in order to have all the parameters of `T`.
For example if `T` is Vue, I would have all Vue parameters such as `$el` or `$options` without re-declaring Vue nor including it.

So I've got the following :

```
export namespace SDK {

  export abstract class Sample<T> {

    private static methods: any = {
      hello: Sample.prototype.hello
    }

    abstract callMe () : void;

    x: number = 0
    y: number = 0
    width: number = 1
    height: number = 1

    hello (): void {
      console.log('Sample hello world')
      this.callMe()
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to process to include the properties of T into Sample.

I would like it to be like:

```
export namespace SDK {

  export abstract class Sample<T> {

    private static methods: any = {
      hello: Sample.prototype.hello
    }

    abstract callMe () : void;

    x: number = 0
    y: number = 0
    width: number = 1
    height: number = 1

    // T properties (Vue example)
    $el: HTMLElement
    ...

    hello (): void {
      console.log('Sample hello world')
      this.callMe()
    }
  }
}
```

I would like my class to be called like:

```
export default class MyComponent extends SDK.Sample<Vue> {
  name: string = 'my-component';

  callMe () : void {
    console.log('called')
  }

  mounted () : void {
    this.hello()
  }
}
```

I did not find anything about extending from a templated class that allow to have parameters in it.

Comment: To clarify: do you wanna extends Sample<T> or Sample extends T? They are different

Comment: I wanna Sample extends T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @TitianCernicovaDragomir basically has it right using mixins.  I have similar code that I will post for completeness, since I think we took slightly different approaches and they have somewhat different advantages and disadvantages.

The following code does enforce that you implement `abstract` methods and gives you access to static members.  But you pay for that by using private unexported names that end up preventing you from making this a library for consumption by others. I think there are workarounds but I don't want to go too far down a rabbit hole with this.

Anyway, here's `Sample`:

```
export namespace SDK {

  export type Constructor<T> = {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
    readonly prototype: T;
  }

  export function Sample<C extends Constructor<{}>>(ctor: C) {
    abstract class Sample extends ctor {
      private static methods: any = {
        hello: Sample.prototype.hello
      }
      abstract callMe(): void;
      x: number = 0
      y: number = 0
      width: number = 1
      height: number = 1

      hello(): void {
        console.log('Sample hello world')
        this.callMe()
      }

    }
    return Sample;
  }

}
```

And its usage:

```
export default class MyComponent extends SDK.Sample(Vue) {
  name: string = 'my-component';

  callMe () : void {
    console.log('called')
  }

  mounted () : void {
    this.hello()
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is **definitely** what I needed. Thanks for the explanations !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend a generic parameter in Typescript (and in C# and Java either for that matter). What you can do is use a [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) approach.

From your requirements below is what I came up with. I did not actually test with Vue (I don't have an environment setup with that library) but the methods and properties are inherited from both classes as expected so it should work with Vue (if you leave a comment with any problems I can look into them).

I found two shortcoming:

1. You loose the compiler warning for not implementing abstract methods
2. You will not be able to access static methods through the derived class.

The function that does the magic

```
function extendSample<T, R extends { new(): T & Sample }>(componentCtor: new () => T): R {
    // Create a new derived class from the component class
    class DerivedComponent extends (<new () => any>componentCtor) {
        constructor() {
            // Call thec omponent constructor
            super();
            // Call out sample class constructor
            Sample.apply(this)
        }
    }
    // Copy instance methods to DerivedComponent
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Sample.prototype).forEach(name => {
        DerivedComponent.prototype[name] = Sample.prototype[name];
    });
    return <R><any>DerivedComponent;
}
```

Sample code :

```
export abstract class Sample {
    abstract callMe(): void;
    x: number = 0
    y: number = 0
    width: number = 1
    height: number = 1

    hello(): void {
        console.log('Sample hello world')
        this.callMe()
    }   
}

export class LibaryComponentBase {
    constructor() {
        this.$el = "HTML "
    }
    $el: string;
    public libraryMethod() {
        console.log("libraryMethod");
    }
    static Test() {

    }
}

export default class MyComponent extends extendSample(LibaryComponentBase) {
    name: string = 'my-component';
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this.$el);
        this.libraryMethod();
        this.hello();
    }

    callMe(): void {
        console.log('called')
    }

    mounted(): void {
        this.hello();
    }
}

let my = new MyComponent();
my.callMe();
```

Comment: Not sure why you're copying methods from the constructor prototype to the mixin prototype.  Doesn't the fact that the mixin `extends` the constructor make that happen automatically?

Comment: @jcalz The constructor will be the library base class (vue for example) the mixin is the sample class. So DerivedComponent gets methods from the library base class through inheritance, and Sample method through copying

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @jcalz approach is more that I expected for now but your point might be useful to me in the future.