# Assign all keys of type to class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a type that I want to somehow assign to a class, so that the class has the same properties as said type.

```
abstract class Model<T> {

    protected options: T

    constructor (options?: Partial<T>) {
        this.options = { ...this.fake(), ...options }
    }

    abstract fake () : T

}

type UserOptions = {
    userName: string,
    email: string,
    roles?: int[]
}

class User extends Model<UserOption> {

    fake () : UserOption {
        return {
            userName: getRandomUsername(),
            email: getRandomEmail()
        }
    }

}
```

With this I am able to create new models and instantiate them without having to fill all the fields. Any field that isn't specified, is just filled with random data. However now I'd like to also access these fields directly, e.g. via `(new User()).userName`. Right now I could make `options` public and access the fields via `.options.userName`, however when I need to access them in a lot of places this becomes quite verbose to write.

Is there a way of generically assigning all these properties to the instance itself while having it properly typed?

Alternatively I was thinking about using Proxies and returning these in other helper methods, rather than the Model itself. That way, to obtain the Proxy a method still had to be called, but the rest of my code will always return the proxy directly. I tried it with this within the `abstract class Model<T>`, but it didn't provide the caller of `user.proxy()` any knowledge about the "existence" of the properties (obviously since the return type is just `this`).

```
proxy () : this {
    return new Proxy(this, {
        get (target, prop: keyof T, receiver) {
            return target.options[prop]
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Relevant question: [Typescript generic class parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47374713/typescript-generic-class-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I don't think there's an easy and type-safe solution for this.  You'd like to be able to make `class Model<T> extends T`, or an equivalent [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html),  but [that's not legal TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13807).  You can make something with sort of the right *type*, but the compiler won't understand that the object is of that type without an [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or two.

I'm going to back up for a second.  It seems that for each `Model<T>` class you really want a *static* `fake()` function that produces a default `T` instance, right?  That is you don't really need access to `this` from within the implementation of `fake()`.  So instead of `new User().fake()` I'd suggest having it be of the form `User.fake()`.

If so, then your `Model` constructor has something like this interface:

```
interface ModelConstructor<T> {
  fake(): T; // static default instance maker
  new(options?: Partial<T>): T; // actual constructor
}
```

And then we can have a function that returns such a constructor, given an appropriate `fake()` function:

```
function makeModel<T extends object>(fake: () => T): ModelConstructor<T> {
  const ret = function (this: T, options?: Partial<T>) {
    Object.assign(this, fake(), options);
  };
  ret.fake = fake;
  // this assertion or something like it is unfortunately necessary
  return ret as any;
}
```

Note that I had to do an assertion because a regular-callable function is not considered assignable to a constructor (newable) type.  (Somewhere there's a GitHub issue which says exactly why they decided not to allow this, but I can't find it right now.  Maybe someone else knows where it is?)

Then you can do something like this:

```
type UserOptions = {
  userName: string,
  email: string,
  roles?: number[]; // not int, what is int?
}

// here is a fake() for Users
function getDefaultUser(): UserOptions {
  return {
    userName: "fred",
    email: "fred@example.com",
    roles: []
  }
}

// make your new constructor:
const User = makeModel(getDefaultUser);
// const User: ModelConstructor<UserOptions>;

// use your constructor:
const user = new User({ userName: "George", email: "george@example.com" });
// const User: UserOptions;
```

Maybe that will give you some ideas on how to proceed.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you! The `makeModel` function that generates a constructor was the right way to go for me. I ended up having the constructor return a Proxy of `this`, so that I could still work with the (protected) `options` object. Also I created new classes such as `class User extends makeModel(getDefaultUser)` in some cases so I could have both all options available and also add methods to the resulting class.