# Constructor signature that returns class with static property

Tags: typescript

As a follow-up to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794886/assign-all-keys-of-type-to-class-in-typescript) from yesterday: I now have a function that returns a class based on its parameters.

```
function Model<T>(name: string, defaults: () => T) : new(options: Partial<T>) => Pick<T, keyof T> {
    return class {
        public _symbol = name

        protected options: T

        constructor (options: Partial<T>) {
            this.options = { ...defaults(), ...options }
            return new Proxy(this, {
                get (target, prop: keyof T) {
                    return target.options[prop]
                }
            })
        }
    } as any
}

type Options {
    username: string,
    email: string
}

class User extends Model<Options>('user', () => ({
    username: getRandomUsername(),
    email: getRandomEmail()
}) {

    sayHello () : void {
        console.log('Hello ' + this.options.username)
    }        

}
```

The Model function accepts a parameter for a name, that will be set into each instance, as well as a function that generates default values. Therefore every `new User()` I create will have a random username and email, but I'm still able to override either of these when I use `new User({ username: 'John' })`.

The resulting type of that constructor function (`Pick<T, keyof T>`) doesn't add any more properties to it, so the `_symbol` property is "lost" to TypeScript when I create a Model (which means `new User()._symbol` won't compile).

A way around that is to have the return type of the `Model` function be something like this:

```
type ModelClass<T> = Pick<T, keyof T> & { _symbol: string }
```

With that, `new User()._symbol` compiles and returns `"user"`. However I don't want `_symbol` to be an instance property, I want it to be a static class property. Unfortunately I can't find any information about how I could modify this new type `ModelClass` to specify a class with a static property. Is there any way to solve this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

As noted this cannot quite work because of the returned `Proxy`. Unless you need the proxy for anything other than returning the passed in/default values you can get rid of it by directly putting all properties on some object instance and returning that.

Here is an example of the class turned into a factory function:

```
export function createModel<T, E extends T>(
    name: string,
    defaults: () => E
)
{
    const factory = (options: Partial<T>) =>
    {
        return { ...defaults(), ...options };
    }

    factory._symbol = name;

    return factory;
}
```

```
type UserOptions = {
    username: string,
    email: string
}
type User = UserOptions & {
    sayHello(): void;
}

const userFactory = createModel<UserOptions, User>(
    'user',
    () => ({
        username: 'a',
        email: 'b',
        sayHello(): void
        {
            console.log('Hello ' + this.username)
        }
    })
);

const steve = userFactory({ username: 'steve' });
console.log(steve.username);
steve.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a non-answer: Just let TS resolve the type automatically.

```
function Model<T>(name: string, defaults: () => T) // Drop return type annotation
{
    return class
    {
        // Change this to public static
        public static _symbol = name

        protected options: T

        constructor(options: Partial<T>)
        {
            this.options = { ...defaults(), ...options }
        }
    } // Drop as cast
}
```

Comment: That does seem like a reasonable idea, but it doesn't compile due to `Property 'options' of exported class expression may not be private or protected.` (even though `options` _is_ marked as protected). Also I would need to annotate some functions as returning an object of a class that inherits this model, for which I'm pretty sure I'd still need a correct type annotation

Comment: Oh it seems to come from me `export default`'ing that function.

Comment: @Padarom: Wonder why that is an issue though.

Comment: So if I make `options` public instead it does compile. It doesn't infer the type properly however, although that is because of something I didn't originally specify in the question (the reason why the type was `Pick<T, keyof T>` before, I edited the question to clarify)

Comment: @Padarom: This does not work in the first place because you cannot return a different object than the constructed class instance from a constructor. If you want to return a proxy, don't return the class but a factory function that constructs the instance but only returns a proxy to it. Of course you will no longer be able to use that in regular inheritance.

Comment: @Padarom: Also, the proxy is broken because it will not return the function `sayHello` when it should.